# Can I start a sentence with "To be mentioned"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Can I start a sentence with *to be mentioned*?

> To be mentioned, Figure 2 has no color because (some clause here).

Comment: _'**Note that** Figure 2 has no color because ...'_ might be more appropriate in this context.

Comment: What do you intend the phrase to mean?

Comment: Obviously you can, you just did in the example. But what you mean (or want it to mean) isn't clear. "Note that" is common, but may or may not be what you want. Please provide more context - what text precedes and succeeds this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***To be mentioned*** does not make sense in your sentence. However, you can say this:

> ***It's worth mentioning***, Figure 2 has no color.

This is a common phrase when you want to point out a fact that might have value to the listener/reader. You could also say ***It's well worth mentioning***.

There are alternative ways of using the phrase on this web page: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/worth-mentioning.1869385/

Comment: I think, if the context is formal, it's better to say, "it's worth mentioning ..."

Comment: I agree with Cardinal - Just **Worth mentioning** by itself sounds very informal.  It would sound better if it were "Worth mentioning is that..."

Comment: @stangdon I changed the answer.

Comment: Or if it's the appropriate context to use the a personal pronoun, *"I might (also) mention that ..."*